# Means to allocate contiguous physical memory

Tags: c, memory

I am aware that with C malloc and posix_memaligh one can allocate contiguous memory from the virtual address space of a process. However, I was wondering whether somehow one can allocate a buffer of physically contiguous memory? I am investigating side channel attacks that exploit L2 cache so I want to be sure that I can access the right cache lines..

Comment: Probably worthwhile examining POSIX interfaces, mmap etc. Whether that makes much difference with side channel attacks, I don't know.

Comment: As @gnasher729 says, it's very OS-specific, and normally nothing but the kernel itself has any reason to want and need to worry about physical addresses at all.

Comment: So, what I am doing here is to use posix_memalign to allocate a chunk of size L2_CACHE_SIZE and I also do align this chunk to the size of the cache line. So the question that I am trying to answer here is whether i can make the assumption that since the allocated virtual memory is aligned to the cache line size, then the corresponding physical memory will be contiguous...

Answer (score 6):

Your best and easiest take at continuous memory is to request a single "huge" page from the system. The availability of those depends on your CPU and kernel options (on x86_64 the 2MB huge pages are usually available and some CPUs can also do 1GB pages; other architectures can be more flexible than this). Check out `Hugepagesize` field in `/proc/meminfo` for the size of huge pages on your setup.

Those can be accessed in two ways:

1. By means of a `MAP_HUGETLB` flag passed to `mmap()`. This way you can be sure that the "huge" virtual page corresponds to a continuous physical memory range. Unfortunately, whether the kernel can supply you with a "huge" page depends on many factors (current layout of memory utilization, kernel options, etc - also see the `hugepages` kernel boot parameter).
2. By means of mapping a file from a dedicated HugeTLB filesystem (see here: http://lwn.net/Articles/375096/). With HugeTLB file system you can configure the number of huge pages available in advance for some assurance that the necessary amount of huge pages will be available.

The other approach is to write a kernel module which will allocate continuous physical memory on the kernel side and then map it into your process' address space on request. This approach is sometimes employed on special purpose hardware in embedded systems. Of course, there's still no guarantee that the kernel side memory allocator will be able to come with an appropriately sized continuous physical address range, so on some occasions such address ranges are pre-reserved on boot (one dumb approach is to pass `max_addr` parameter to kernel on boot to leave some of the RAM out of kernel's reach).

Answer (score 0):

On (almost [Note 1]) all virtual memory architectures, virtual memory is mapped to physical memory in units of a "page". The size of a page is (almost) always a power of 2, and pages are aligned by that size, because the mapping is done by only using the high-order bits of the address. It's common to see a page size of 4K (12 bits of address), although modern CPUs have an option to map much larger pages in order to reduce the size of mapping tables.

Since `L2_CACHE_SIZE` will generally also be a power of 2 and will be smaller than the page size, any single aligned allocation of size `L2_CACHE_SIZE` will necessarily be in a single page, so the bytes in the alignment will be physically contiguous as well.

So in this particular case, you can be assured that your allocated memory will be a single cache-line (at least, on standard machine architectures).

---

Note 1: Undoubtedly there are machines -- possibly imaginary -- which do not function this way. But the one you are playing with is not one of them.

Comment: In my case the size of the L2 cache is 256K which is definitely larger than the page size of 4K.

Comment: @Mimo: But you don't need the memory to be physically contiguous; you only need the individual cache lines allocations to be actual cache lines. The L2 cache itself is a collection of individual cache lines; whether two adjacent cache lines map adjacent physical (or virtual) memory is irrelevant.